# Can't get option list from a select

Tags: java, list, html-select

here is my html:

[image: enter link description here]

The solution was simple, i put a select object and get thougth the method `getAllOptions` but it doesn't work and know i'm doing this to get not the id (value) i want the option's text:

```
WebElement optionElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id=\"" + selectToFind + "\"]/option["+ randomItemIndex + "]"));

optionSelected = optionElement.getText();
```

being `selectToFind` the select's id which is `FORM_FIELD_EndUser_planning` and `randomItemIndex` which comes from a method that returns a random value taking in account the size of options in the list:

```
List <WebElement> itemsInDropdown = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@id=\""+ selectToFind + "\"]/option"));
```

All tries of the object optionElement (like .getText()) returns "" and i'm stuck with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
option.getAttribute("innerText");
```

or

```
option.getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Or expand your Select element (by click) and then try to get a text of options because .getText() method returns only visible text

Comment: option.getAttribute("innerText") works perfectly! Many thanks!